Is there a characterization of measurables in terms of indiscernibles?
There is a characterization of $\alpha$-Erdős cardinals in terms of sets of indiscernibles of order type $\alpha$. There is also a characterization of Ramsey cardinals in terms of sets of good indiscernibles of cardinality $\kappa$, which are a strengthened special case of indiscernibles. Both of these characterizations are listed with sources on the two linked Cantor's Attic pages for these cardinals.
Is there a similar characterization for measurable cardinals, one of the form "$\kappa$ is measurable iff structure A has a set of B-indiscernibles", where A is some structure relating to $\kappa$ (e.g. $(V_\kappa,\in)$, $(L_\kappa,\in)$, or an arbitrary structure of cardinality $\kappa$), and B-indiscernibility is some notion that is a strengthening of indiscernibility?

I have one lower bound on quantifier complexity, which is that if the structure A used in the characterization is $(V_\kappa,\in)$, and $\psi(I)$ is a formula formalizing the B-indiscernibility condition used (i.e. $I\subseteq\kappa$ is a set of B-indiscernibles iff $(V_\kappa,\in)\vDash\psi(I)$), then $\psi(I)$ cannot be a $\Pi^2_1$ formula (a third-order formula with its only third-order quantifiers unbounded universal), since the least measurable cardinal is $\Pi^2_1$-indescribable. (Kanamori, The Higher Infinite, p. 61)
In contrast, for any $\alpha<\kappa$, I believe the statement "$I$ is a set of indiscernibles for $(V_\kappa,\in)$" is $\Sigma^1_2$ with $I$ as a second-order free variable. (This is not strictly part of either the Erdős or Ramsey characterization, but it demonstrates how much higher in quantifier complexity an indiscernible-based characterization of measurables would have to be, at least if the A used is $(V_\kappa,\in)$.)

Isn't in $\Sigma^2_1$ over $V_\kappa$ to say that $\kappa$ is measurable? I.e. just say "there is a $\kappa$-complete non-principal ultrafilter over $\kappa$".

@FarmerS Oops, you're right. I'll also remove the "not" in order to make the argument work.
